# Passing multiple arguments to a function taken from dataframe

Tags: r, function, dataframe

going to try and simplify this so that it's easier to explain.  Let's say you have a function:

```
testfun = function(jID,kID,d){
  g=paste0(jID,kID)
  date = d
  bb=data.frame(g,date)
  return(bb)
}
```

and a dataframe:

```
x=data.frame(jID = c("a","b"),kID=c("c","d"),date="20170206",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I'd like to pass each row into the functions inputs:

so cycle 1:

```
testfun(x[1,1],x[1,2],x[1,3]) -> return(bb)
```

cycle 2:

```
testfun(x[2,1],x[2,2],x[2,3]) -> return(bb)
```

I've tried using `mapply(testfun, x[,1],x[,2],x[,3])` but i'm getting back sort of a summary.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution using `dplyr`.
The key is to group by row and run your function for each row.
The function's output should create new columns in a new dataset, next to the values you used.

```
 library(dplyr)

testfun = function(jID,kID,d){
  g=paste0(jID,kID)
  date = d
  bb=data.frame(g,date)
  return(bb)
}


x=data.frame(jID = c("a","b"),kID=c("c","d"),date="20170206",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


x %>% do(data.frame(.,                                     # keep row of your dataset
                    testfun(.$jID, .$kID, .$date)))        # run the function using the values of that row

#   jID kID     date  g   date.1
# 1   a   c 20170206 ac 20170206
# 2   b   d 20170206 bd 20170206
```

Note that the process creates a new column `date.1` as `date` exists for one of your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you just want to turn off simplification

```
mapply(testfun, x[,1],x[,2],x[,3], SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

You can also vectorize your function

```
vtestfun <- (Vectorize(testfun, SIMPLIFY=FALSE))
vtestfun(x[,1],x[,2],x[,3])
```