# Pass multiple arguments to function from dataframe with unknown number of columns

Tags: r, dataframe, function

I have a function similar to this:

```
testfun = function(jID,kID,d){
  g=paste0(jID,kID)
  date = d
  bb=data.frame(g,date)
  return(bb)
}
```

Data frame:

```
x=data.frame(jID = c("a","b"),kID=c("c","d"),date="20170206",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I want to pass each row as inputs into the function. The solutions provided here: [Passing multiple arguments to a function taken from dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42281510/passing-multiple-arguments-to-a-function-taken-from-dataframe) are great but in their case, the number of columns was known. How would a solution like this:

```
vtestfun <- (Vectorize(testfun, SIMPLIFY=FALSE))
vtestfun(x[,1],x[,2],x[,3])
```

be applied if the number of columns in the dataframe is not known or keeps changing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can match the argument names to the column names like so:

```
testfun <- function(jID, kID, date){ # 'date', not 'd'
  g    <- paste0(jID, kID)
  bb   <- data.frame(g, date)
  return(bb)
}
```

You could do:

```
purrr::pmap(x, testfun)
```

Returning:

```
[[1]]
   g     date
1 ac 20170206

[[2]]
   g     date
1 bd 20170206
```

```
# Data used:
x <- structure(list(jID = c("a", "b"), kID = c("c", "d"), date = c("20170206", "20170206")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: How would this work if _jID_ and _kID_ are separate data frames with unequal numbers of rows and columns? For example, _jID_ has dimensions of 4 by 2 and _kID_ has dimensions of 7 by 5 ? @ktiu

Comment: Depends on how you want to match the rows that go in the same function call. I would asking another question with appropriate sample data, feel free to link me to it :)